In Oracle oml4r, library(ORE) is not working after install
After getting rstudio server to work, I followed these instruction to enable oml4r - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/2.0.0/oread/install-rstudio-server.html. In particular I did the following:
'''
sudo vi /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf
rsession-ld-library-path=R_HOME/lib:ORACLE_HOME/lib
'''
'''
cd /usr/lib64/R/etc
sudo vi Renviron.site
ORACLE_HOME=ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=ORACLE_HOSTNAME
ORACLE_SID=ORACLE_SID
'''
'''
sudo rstudio-server restart
'''
But I was still not able to execute library(ORE). Are there other packages that need to be loaded? If so, how should I load them?
